# Given a JPG of a wallpaper, how can I find the smallest section which contains the pattern?

Tags: graphics, tiling

I recently made the photo

[image]

of tapestry, but I am not able to identify the smallest patch which contains the pattern.

Now I wonder: How could I write a program that does so?

A first step could be identifying axis-aligned bounding boxes (AABBs). The most simple way I can think of is having a combined quality metric:

$$error = MSE + pattern\ area$$

to combine two problems:

- get a small pattern area
- get a small MSE (and MSE gets better with bigger patterns)

Then just take many possible AABBs and compute their scores. The MSE would simply take the color difference in HS (HSL without L) color space.

**How is this problem called?** What are current state of the art solutions?
Are there algorithms which also work on more complex shapes / repetition patterns than AABBs? Can I rotate the image optimally / take shearing into account?

Comment: I saw "JPG" and "wallpaper" in your title and thought I was going to have to flag for migration to [su]. :-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Not this time :-P